# I want Abode Reader DC to open in full screen mode

Tags: adobe-reader, pdf-reader

When I open a PDF document in Abode Reader DC I get three windows. The left windows says Bookmark and a bunch of choices. In the middle is the PDF document itself and on the right is Export PDF and a bunch of other choices. I do not want the left and right windows. I want the image of the PDF to fill the whole page. I tried fiddling with the preferences but I couldn't get it to change.

[image]

Comment: You can try "Read Mode" <ctrl><h> or "Full Screen Mode" <ctrl><l>. That's only 2 key presses ...

Comment: This worked fine. However I want to open it full screen mode without pressing any keys. The reason is I am integrating this into a product that uses a WebBrower control.